# Some Questions regarding the Immutable pattern

Tags: java, design-patterns

I have some questions regarding the immutable pattern. First of all to solve the problem we need to ensure the following :

1)Instance methods which access properties must not change instance variables.

2) Ensure that the constructor of the immutable class is the only place where the
   values of instance variables are set or **modified**.
I think that by making the inctance variables as final variables , then if there exists a method that changes this variable will fail , even the constructor will not be able to change this variable , so why we need to put into considerations these two statements if we can use the final keyword ?? I know that i am missing something.

Answer (score 2):

There is one important thing for making real immutables. Maybe the components are mutable data structures such as `java.util.Date`. Take this simple class for demonstration purposes:

```
final class DateWrapper {
  private final Date date;
  public DateWrapper(Date date) {
    this.date = date;
  }
  public Date getDate() {
    return date;
  }
}
```

Now you can write this code:

```
DateWrapper dw = new DateWrapper(new Date());
dw.getDate().setYear(2020);
```

This modifies the instance variable `date` of the object `dw` of class `DateWrapper`. So this class is not really immutable.

To solve this problem, you have to make defensive copies like this:

```
final class DateWrapper {
  private final Date date;
  public DateWrapper(Date date) {
    // It must not be possible to modify the date after construction.
    // So use a copy of the original object in class DateWrapper.
    this.date = new Date(date.getTime());
  }
  public Date getDate() {
    // It must not be possible to modify the date in DateWarapper
    // So return a copy.
    return new Date(date.getTime());
  }
}
```

So no other class will get a mutable reference to `DateWrapper`'s internals.

Another rule is: Make your class final, or otherwise a subclass can behave as an immutabele class, breaking the contract of immutablility. This is an example of a malicious subclass, that works only, if DateWrapper is not final:

```
class Date2Wrapper extends DateWrapper {
  final Date date2;
  public Date2Wrapper(Date date) {
    super(date);
    this.date2 = date;
  }
  public Date getDate() {
    return date2;
  }
}
```

Comment: To tackle the issue you've described you not only make a defensive copy in the `getDate` method but as well in the constructor. That is because of the reference passed to the constructor might be changed outside which makes your class mutable as well.

Comment: @Hannes it looks like he is instantiating a new Date object in his constructor using a value from the Date object passed in, defending the class itself from changes made to that reference

Comment: Yes, it is also necessary to make a defensive copy in the constructor. I didn't mention this explictly in my text. I have now included the information in the comment of the java code.

Comment: @Donat - what do you think `static` in `final static class DateWrapper` does ?

Comment: @David Soroko: Sorry, this was a mistake by cut and paste. I had it in my IDE as an inner class to check for syntax problems. In my test case I used static classes. The difference of static and non-static inner classes is another story. Thanks for asking.

Comment: @Donat - np. Can you explain how can a subclass of `DateWrapper` "get access to the internals " if `DateWrapper`  was not final?

Comment: @David Soroko: This was not quite exact. I will modify my answer accordingly.

Comment: @donat  Thank you very much , but can yu please provide another basic example as this example is confusing for me ?

Comment: @Adam Johnson: Would you please ask a more specific question? I connot imagine what is confusing to you. Maybe, it will be simpler this way.

Answer (score 1):

First of all design patterns are not limited to java. They can be implemented in different languages, having different flavor. Not all languages have a final, even java didn't have finals from the beginning.

But considering the strict case of java, final does not ensure immutability:

- in an object the state can be changed using methods of members if they are accessible.
- final applied to an object ensures the variable points to the same object, but does not put any restriction to avoid changing the state( ball.setColor("red") can be executed on a final ball )
- immutability means that a variable should be re-assignable wit another object

For example:

```
Ball ball = new Ball(); 
ball = ball.makeRed();
```

In this case, ball is another ball object( make ball clones the ball and change the color ). The same happens when we run a method on a String object, a new string object is created to reflect the changes and returned:

```
String ball = 'Blue Ball';
ball = ball.replace('Blue', 'Red');
```

Comment: can you please provide a simple example where with a setter method we can change the state of an immutable object after intialaziation ?